# How to remap an array to save it to couples

Tags: php, html

I need to remap an array from

```
array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

to output in couples like this:

```
array(1,2)
array(3,4)
array(5,6)
```

which I can do with foreach, but is the an built in php function that does this for you?

Comment: Use PHP's [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function

Comment: could you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
<?php
$in  = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$out = array_chunk($in, 2);
```